# Coffee spill on Laptop, still works - though for how long?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, asus

Now back a week ago I spilled coffee with sugar in it on my keyboard. When the spill happened, I quickly turned it off and turned it upside down dried it with a tissue and all that stuff. I waited for a total of 3 days before I turned it on again and even went to a repair shop to have it checked. The people there kept telling me if its working I shouldnt have it cleaned or it might stop working entirely. But here on internet people keep saying that coffee should be cleaned asap. I dont know what to do at the moment and Im afraid of what unseen damage there could be on the motherboard, I dont care if its just the keyboard.

To summerize:
I spilled coffee, laptop works, waited for 72 hours+ to dry, repairmen keep telling I shouldnt have it cleaned. Should I trust them?

Comment: This is the canonical answer from Ask Different. You got lucky so far, doing all the wrong things - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271

Comment: This is actually my favourite answer on the water-spill issue… not so subtle as the canonical one ;) https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275